# union of regular language and non regular language

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-language

I have the languages $L_1 = 00^*\{1^n0^n \mid n \geqslant 0\}$ and $L_2 = 0^*1^*$. 
I know that $L_1$ is not regular and $L_2$ is.
But is $L = L_1 + L_2$ is not regular?
An extended explanation will be much appreciated :)

Comment: Can you tell me what $L_1 \cup L_2$ is as a language? What strings are in it?

Comment: Also, do you mean $0(0^*)$ or $(00)^*$ for $L_1$?

Comment: @HallaSurvivor in the given exercise the union it's L1 + L2, nothing else is given. They asked us if the union is regular or not, and explain why.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor in L1 I meant the left option in your question

Comment: Right - I'm asking if you can tell me what strings are in the language. Then we can decide if it's regular from there. I'm trying to walk you through the problem, rather than giving an immediate answer

Comment: @HallaSurvivor there can be words that must start with zero and after that can have some zeroes(or not) and then there must be an equal number of 1 and 0 in the word(the letters 1 are beside each other.. no zero between them) 
In another case, you can have epsilon, some zeroes at the beginning of the word(then 1, or not) or have only letters of 1 in the word. I hope I could explain it well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $L_3$ be the regular language $01^+0^+$. If $L_1 + L_2$ were regular, then $(L_1 + L_2) \cap L_3$ would also be regular. Now
$$
(L_1 + L_2) \cap L_3 = 0\{1^n0^n \mid n > 0\}
$$
which is not regular.

Answer (score 0):

The strings in the language $L_1 \cup L_2$ take one of the following two forms:

- $00^k1^n0^n$
- $0^k1^n$

We know that the strings in the first case are irregular, but as soon as we see a $0$ after a $1$ (which *is* a regular thing to check), we *know* we must be in the first case. This is some heuristic evidence that $L_1 \cup L_2$ isn't regular.

How can we make this formal?

Well, let's fix a supposed DFA for $L_1 \cup L_2$. What would it have to do with the inputs $01, 011, 0111, 01111, \ldots$?

By the pigeonhole principle, we must have $01^i$ and $01^j$ end up in the same state (since there are only finitely many states the machine can be in, but there are infinitely many strings of the form $01^n$).

But if $01^i$ and $01^j$ are in the same state, then $01^i0^i$ and $01^j0^i$ are *also* in the same state.

Now we see the problem - is this an accepting state? If it is, then we accidentally accept $01^j0^i$, which isn't in the language. If it isn't, then we accidentally omit $01^i0^i$, even though it is in the language. So no DFA properly accepts $L_1 \cup L_2$, and it is irregular.

The important thing to notice, and what I was trying to bring to your attention in the comments, was that unioning $L_1$ with $0^*1^*$ has no way of helping you! We can easily identify if we're in $L_1$ or $L_2$ based on the form of the string. As soon as we've read a $0$ after a $1$, we *know* the only strings that have a chance of being accepted are those in $L_1$, and so the exact argument that shows $L_1$ is irregular also shows that $L_1 \cup L_2$ is irregular!

---

I hope this helps ^_^